# Attaching AWS Managed Policy to a Custom Role via Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing a tf script to create a role and attach an AWS Managed Policy to the Role. If my policy is a custom policy this works, If i need to use a an AWS managed policy, how do i attach my policy to the role. is there a way to use "data" to extrapolate the role ARN from AWS

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "CloudWatchAgentServerRole" {
  name               = "CloudWatchAgentServerRole"
  description        = "Role created to allow Memory metrics to CloudWatch "
  assume_role_policy = file("role.json")
}

#Create Policy - Not Required as its an AWS Managed Policy
/*resource "aws_iam_policy" "CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy" {
  name        = "CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
  description = "Permissions required to use AmazonCloudWatchAgent on servers"
  policy      = file("policy.json")
}*/

# Attach Policy 
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "CloudWatchAgentServer" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.CloudWatchAgentServerRole.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy.arn  
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ARN for an AWS managed policy is going to be `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/` followed by the policy name. There's really no need to look it up using a `data` element, since it will always be in that format. So to attach the policy in your example you would use the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "CloudWatchAgentServer" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.CloudWatchAgentServerRole.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. That is what i did to overcome the issue. but was curios to know if there was another way to pull this via data

Comment: The `aws_iam_policy` data element requires you to pass the ARN for the lookup, so there isn't any point in using it here.

Comment: Thanks Again Mark

Comment: I had to hardcode the policy arn, it didn't work with the data lookup.